# Merging cross-sectional data to panel data without NA rows

Tags: r, merge, data.table, panel-data, longitudinal

I have 15 data tables for the years 2005 - 2020 like this:

```
DT_2005 = data.table(
  ID = c("1","2","3","4","5","6"),
  year = c("2005,"2005","2005","2005","2005","2005")
  score = c("98","89","101","78","97","86")
)

# Data tables for every year...

DT_2020 = data.table(
  ID = c("1","2","4","6","7","8"),
  year = c("2020,"2020","2020","2020","2020","2020")
  score = c("89","79","110","98","74","88")
)

# DT_2020 output
ID, year, score
1, 2020, 89
2, 2020, 79
4, 2020, 110
6, 2020, 98
7, 2020, 74
8, 2020, 88
```

i.e. there are ID's that don't appear in some years.

I want to combine the tables into a "long" format like this:

```
ID, year, score
1, 2005, 98
1, 2006, 95
1, 2007, 97
...
1, 2019, 90
1, 2020, 89
2, 2005, 79
2, 2006, 81
...
2, 2019, 83
2, 2020, 79
```

Is there a way to do this in `data.table` so that each row is an `ID` with the years in ascending order and there are no `NA` rows for `ID`'s that weren't in a certain year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine all the dataframes in one combined dataframes from the global environment and order the results.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- rbindlist(mget(paste0('DT_', c(2005:2020))))
dt <- dt[order(ID)]
```

The equivalent `dplyr` and base R alternatives are -

```
#dplyr
library(dplyr)
res <- bind_rows(mget(paste0('DT_', c(2005:2020)))) %>% arrange(ID)


#Base R
res <- do.call(rbind, mget(paste0('DT_', c(2005:2020))))
res <- res[order(res$ID), ]
```